# Adding custom font ttf not working

Tags: html, css, truetype

I'm trying to add new fonts to my website. Just got the TTF file of the font I want (Gill Sans Light). Here is my test code

**`main.css`** :-

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans Light';
    src: url('fonts/gill-sans-light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**`index.html`** :-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>     
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="landing">
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="title">
                    <span style="font-family: 'Gill Sans Light'">Testing Font</span>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I open `index.html` in a browser it doesn't work. Moreover, on Chrome it shows the error -

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    gill-sans-light.ttf
```

Which makes no sense to me, because the file **is** there and I've triple checked for filename errors.

I know there are a ton of related questions. But none of the solutions are really helping me. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `gill-sans-light.ttf` should exist in the following path:

```
css/fonts/gill-sans-light.ttf
```

You `main.css` file is inside the `css` folder, and the reference is to `fonts/gill-sans-light.ttf`, so this path should be inside the `css` folder.

Comment: Could have happen to everyone :) Glad I could help.